# Hiding or showing value based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a form and part of it requires the user to select whether they would like collection or postage. What I have partially works but because the the value for one of the radio buttons is 7.25 it does not work for some reason.

This the radio button part of the form:

```
<p>Would you like postage(£7.25 extra) or to collect from one of our shops?</p>
<label class="checkbox-inline"></label>
    <input type="radio" required name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="delivery" value="7.25">Postage
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="collection" value="0"/>Collection

    <div id="7.25" class="desc">
       You have chosen postage
    </div>
    <div id="0" class="desc">
       You have chosen collection
    </div>
```

And this is the script I have at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='delivery[]']").click(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + choice).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Like I said this would work if the value was a whole number but because of the . it does not for some reason. Why is this the case and how do I sort this? The values of the radio buttons are numbers as this affects the total price

Comment: because it's number. dont use numbers for id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `$("#7.25")` it believes that `7` is the ID and `25` is a class, because `.` represents a class.

Also, you should not use numbers as ID. If you do want a number in the ID, start with a letter like `k_7`

There are many ways to fix this, in the example below, I've added `data-descTarget="k_0"` to the `inputs` and changed the ids of the div's.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.desc").hide();
  $("input[name$='delivery[]']").click(function() {
    var choice = $(this).attr("data-descTarget");
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#" + choice).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Would you like postage(£7.25 extra) or to collect from one of our shops?</p>
<label class="checkbox-inline"></label>
<input type="radio" required name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="delivery" data-descTarget="k_0" value="7.25">Postage
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="collection" data-descTarget="k_1" value="0"/>Collection

    <div id="k_0" class="desc">
       You have chosen postage
    </div>
    <div id="k_1" class="desc">
       You have chosen collection
    </div>
```

Comment: okay, how should I change it then? because it only works if the id is the same as the value of the radio button

Comment: the showing of the div only works if the id of the div is the same as the value of the radio button

Comment: so 'You have chosen collection' works because the div id is 0 and the value of the radio button is 0, if I change one of these it stops working

Comment: @LewisRoss try run the demo

Comment: thanks a lot, that works great and thanks for the explanation for why it didn't work. Just so I know for the future, what is so bad about having a number as an id?

Comment: Try and read here, it explains a lot http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a read, really appreciate the explanations and your help :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help, that's why we are here.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. as you cant put id with `.` and you should not use number as id. you could use data attribute.

```
<p>Would you like postage(£7.25 extra) or to collect from one of our shops?</p>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" required name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="delivery" value="7.25">Postage
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="delivery[]" class="photo" id="collection" value="0"/>Collection
</label>
<div data-id="7.25" class="desc">
  You have chosen postage
</div>
<div data-id="0" class="desc">
  You have chosen collection
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='delivery[]']").click(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
       $('*[data-id="'+choice+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hmuk0xg/

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't select #7.25 in jQuery, but you can do it using vanillaJS!

intead of `$("#" + choice).show();`

Write this `$(document.getElementById(choice)).show();`